Client policy in keycloak authorization server return Deny for allowed client
I configure keycloak (quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:24.0.2) with two clients:

store-700
my-resource-server

I also set my my-resource-server as a resource server and set it like that:

created scope named upload
created resource named transaction (with scope: upload)
created policy named 'store-clients': type of Client Policy (and allow client-id store-700)
created permission named 'permission-700' which allow access to transaction:upload

this is my overall configuration:
{
"allowRemoteResourceManagement": true,
"policyEnforcementMode": "ENFORCING",
"resources": [
    {
        "name": "transaction",
        "ownerManagedAccess": false,
        "displayName": "",
        "attributes": {},
        "_id": "e61bc461-85d4-4390-af7b-d594c5f4c6d7",
        "uris": [],
        "scopes": [
            {
                "name": "upload"
            }
        ],
        "icon_uri": ""
    }
],
"policies": [
    {
        "id": "c2fec000-591d-41e2-94e7-6062bca6ca5b",
        "name": "store-clients",
        "description": "",
        "type": "client",
        "logic": "POSITIVE",
        "decisionStrategy": "UNANIMOUS",
        "config": {
            "clients": "[\"store-700\"]"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "82cdb7dd-a70b-4272-abbd-f9d941fbdd27",
        "name": "permission-700",
        "description": "",
        "type": "scope",
        "logic": "POSITIVE",
        "decisionStrategy": "UNANIMOUS",
        "config": {
            "resources": "[\"transaction\"]",
            "scopes": "[\"upload\"]",
            "applyPolicies": "[\"store-clients\"]"
        }
    }
],
"scopes": [
    {
        "id": "9b14076d-17a9-42a8-a8ac-a0c98dc253ca",
        "name": "upload",
        "iconUri": ""
    }
],
"decisionStrategy": "UNANIMOUS"}

When I am trying to evaluate this in the Evaluate tab I get Deny:


What I don't understand is why I am getting Deny on that? if this client is allowed by the policy why the policy vote to deny the authorization request?

The Deny makes sense due to the client store-700 have no relationship with user service-account-store-700.
So you need to create user policy and assign it user is service-account-store-700.

Add a user-policy to permission-700 Permission.
And change Decision strategy from Unanimous to Affirmative
The decision strategy dictates how the policies associated with a given permission are evaluated and how a final decision is obtained. 'Affirmative' means that at least one policy must evaluate to a positive decision in order for the final decision to be also positive. 'Unanimous' means that all policies must evaluate to a positive decision in order for the final decision to be also positive. 

The Evaluate will be Permit due to user assigned to user-policy and permission-700 has it and Affirmative strategy will make 'Permit` decision.



Thank you. I'm still puzzled as to why I'm unable to exclusively rely on the Client policy to grant authorization to a specific client. Even during evaluation, I find myself needing to supply a User (or Role). My understanding was that the Client policy would afford me the capability to authorize only the designated clients without requiring a User input.
